# Embed window icon to EXE with Pyinstaller

Tags: wxpython, pyinstaller

I'm building a Windows one file executable of my wxPython app with Pyinstaller. I want to add a window icon and doing `pyinstaller --icon=test.ico --onefile --noconsole test.pyw` is perfectly fine only if I put the test.ico file just next to the builded executable. This makes me distribute both the exe and the icon, and that's at least uncomfortable.

I also do

```
icon = wx.EmptyIcon()
icon.CopyFromBitmap(wx.Bitmap("test.ico", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY))
self.SetIcon(icon)
```

in my wxPython app.

My research says a suggestion to hardcode a base64 string representation of the icon but it's an insanely long string as I also need to print on paper my code. I saw [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile) and I sense it has my answer but I just don't understand it.

So. How can I embed the icon to the exe?

EDIT: `.spec` file

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['test.pyw'],
         pathex=['D:\\test'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      name='test',
      debug=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      console=False , icon='test.ico')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, with `--icon` option you already have included the `.ico` into your executable. But wxPython has no way to extract it from the `.exe` (I suppose it would not be all that hard by using windows system calls, but that is not the point).

Therefore you have to include the `.ico`-file a second time, this time into the file system.

The [stackoverflow article linked by you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile) already has the answers:

1. Modify the `.spec` file to include the icon file into the bundled application.
2. When running the application, it will decompress the bundled files in a temporary location. As pointed out in the article referenced by you, the resource path is specified in `sys._MEIPASS`. Do not forget to consider subdirectories (e. g. a `images` for `./images/icon.ico`) when forming the full file qualifier.

Show your `.spec` file modification and the code retrieving the icon to get further help

Comment: Edited as requested. So you say I just need to add that code in to my app? But where and how?

Comment: On ``CopyFromBitmap``, replace ``"test.ico"`` with the result from the call to ``resource_path`` as described in the other stackoverplow post. And in your spec file you have still add the ``test.ico`` to ``a.datas`` (remember, ``icon=`` adds the icon to the binary).

Comment: Perfect. Just for the record, it is needed to add the function in that article to the wxPython script. I did not as a class' method but outside it. Working fine.